# place Notify OSD on top of Screen Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, notify-osd

I was wondering if I can rearrange the NotifyOSD to the top bar.
I am currently using Gnome3 on Ubuntu 11.04 with Zukitwo Theme and the Notification Bar is in the bottom of the screen. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The [Reflection GNOME Shell extension](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/get-classic-gnome-desktop-with-these.html) may be able to do this for you, although everything else will be switched around as well. This is the closest solution I can find.